# LEAFLET (interactive maps) - Markers with Custom Icons with Spring MVC Framework (Static content)

Tags: spring-mvc, leaflet, ui-leaflet

I am using leafletjs inside a  Spring MVC Framework app. 
I want to use custom Icons using costum images for different icons.

This is the hierarchy of my project:

```
webaapp
   --- core
-------- css
-------- js
-----------images (leafletjs images)
```

Here the code

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/css/leaflet.css" />
    <title>leafletjs</title>
    </head>
    <body>


THIS IMAGE IS OK, I CAN SEE IT:
        <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/images/marker-icon-2x-blue.png"/>

        <div id="mapid" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>


        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/js/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script>

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution:
                    'osm',
                id: 'mapbox.streets'
            }).addTo(mymap);

            var greenIcon  = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),
                redIcon    = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-red.png'}),
                blueIcon   = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-blue.png'}),
                yellowIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-yellow.png'});



            L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(mymap)
                .bindPopup(" ").openPopup();

            L.marker([51.49, -0.091], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(mymap)
            .bindPopup(" ").openPopup();

            L.marker([51.48, -0.092], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(mymap)
            .bindPopup("").openPopup();

            L.marker([51.47, -0.098], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(mymap)
            .bindPopup(" ").openPopup();

            var popup = L.popup();


        </script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

If I don't custimaze the image I see that the default marker icon is here and it shows up perfectly:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x.png
```

but for the custom ones I've tried several things without success:

```
new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),

new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'images/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),

new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '/images/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),

new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),

new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),
```

adding an alert('${pageContext.request.contextPath})' within the inner content of my script to see what it resolves, the message is the contect name of my Application:   **/myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT**

I also tried with

```
<spring:url value="/resources/core/js/images/marker-icon-2x-green.png" var="myImage" />
 var greenIcon  = new LeafIcon({iconUrl:'${myImage}'})
```

it didn't work either, even in the JSP  works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** following edits 8-12 of the question:

Alright, If I understand correctly, you added your custom icon images in the same `images` folder as Leaflet default icon?

In that case, you could take advantage of Leaflet default icon image automatic path resolution `L.Icon.Default.imagePath` to build your own path.

I guess something like:

```js
new LeafIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + '/marker-icon-2x-green.png'});
```

---

Where do you define your `LeafIcon`?

What does `'${pageContext.request.contextPath}'` resolves to within the inner content of your script?

Have you tried `'resources/core/images/marker-icon-2x-green.png'`? (notice the absence of leading slash)